# Why is this an infinite loop in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

This is my script:

```
for (int Card1 = Card1player2->Caption.ToInt();    Card1 > 0 && Number - 10 >= 0; Card1 - 1)
{ 
Number - 10; 
Sleep(1000); Pictureplayer2->Picture->LoadFromFile("/*Plaatje*/");
}
```

I work with c++ builder.

ps...
these are my variables:

```
Card1player2->Caption.ToInt() = 4

Number = 20
```

Comment: because Card1 > 0 && Number - 10 >= 0; is always true

Comment: You're not assigning anything. `Card1 = Card1-1`?

Comment: What programming language did you use before? prolog?

Comment: Okey, this question is clearly a case where I miss terribly the "Should have a minimal understanding of the problem" close reason.

Comment: @JBL give the guy a break, just because it is a beginners problem does not make it a bad question.  We all started somewhere once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an infinite loop at least because you never change the values of any variables that control the loop termination. Expression `Card1 - 1` does nothing material, expression `Number - 10` does nothing as well. They simply calculate the result and then discard it.

In you intend to decrement `Card1` on each iteration, you have to make sure that you actually *store* the new value in `Card1` instead of discarding it. You can do it as `Card1 = Card1 - 1`. Alternatively, you can use "shorthand" forms like `--Card1` or `Card1 -= 1`, which do the same thing. But what you have now simply has no effect.

Comment: Are you sure? Card1 -1 and Number - 10.

Comment: @Luc: Those say *please compute Card1-1 and throw away the result*.

Comment: I explicitly didn't want to hint at `Card1 = Card1 - 1` in my answer, but if you go for completness, you should probably also mention `Card1--`.

Comment: " discarding it"... was that a pun? ;)

Answer (score 4):

`Card1 - 1;` does **not** change the value of `Card1`. It creates a temporary `int` holding the result of the subtraction, which is not used and immediately thrown away.

You must use the `-=` operator:

```
Card -= 1;
```

Or, since you are subtracting 1, you can also use `--`:

```
--Card;
```

Same problem with `Number - 10;`.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the values of `Number` or `Card1` so the loop can't ever end.  I think you want something more like:

```
for (/* ...your stuff... */; --Card1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int Card1 = Card1player2->Caption.ToInt();    Card1 > 0 && (Number - 10) >= 0; Card1--)
{ 
   Number -= 10; 
   Sleep(1000); Pictureplayer2->Picture->LoadFromFile("/*Plaatje*/");
 }
```

Comment: For consistency, one should prefer pre-decrement to post-decrement.